# Error in action file PHP

Tags: php

I have one file, that file is a form for administrator change Username and Password. The file named "change_password.php". Here's the code :

```
<?php 
session_start();    
include_once('../config.php');
?>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">  -->
        <title>***********</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="Login and Registration Form with HTML5 and CSS3" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="html5, css3, form, switch, animation, :target, pseudo-class" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style2.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/animate-custom.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
            <!-- Codrops top bar -->
            <div class="codrops-top">
              <div class="clr"></div>
            </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->
 <header>
          </header>

<section>

 <div id="container_demo" >
                    <!-- hidden anchor to stop jump http://www.css3create.com/Astuce-Empecher-le-scroll-avec-l-utilisation-de-target#wrap4  -->
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="signup" class="animate form">
<form  action="change.php" autocomplete="on" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                                <h1>Admin's Profile Account</h1>         

  <?php 
            $admin_id = $_GET['id_admin'];

            $query = mysql_query("select * from administrator where ID_Admin='$admin_id'");

            $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);?>

             <p>
              <label for="username">Username : </label>
              <input id="username" name="username" class="wide" type="text" required="required" value="<?php echo $data['username']; ?>"/>
              <input id="username2" name="username2" class="wide" type="hidden" required="required" value="<?php echo $data['username']; ?>"/>
             </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">New Password :</label><input id="password" name="password" class="wide" type="password" required="required" placeholder="Your password" />
            </p>
            <p>
                     <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password : </label> <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" class="wide" type="password" required="required" placeholder="Confirm your password" />
            </p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

 <center><p class="signup button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</p></center>
</form>
 <center><a href="panelAdmin.php">Panel Administrator</a></center>                     
</div>  
        </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have one action file for changing username and password for Administrator. The file named "change.php". When I try to change username and password, this file only just blank. It didn't redirecting to another page. So where's my mistake? I tried to change the part of if else and another but the result is still the same. Here's my code :

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once('../config.php');

$ID_Admin   = $_POST['admin_id'];
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];
$encrypt    = md5($password);
$confirm_pass   = $_POST['confirm_password'];

if ($confirm_pass != $password) {
    echo" <script language='JavaScript'> alert ('Password doesn't match');</script>";
    echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href ="change_password.php" </script>';
} else {
    if($_POST['username'] != $_POST['username2']){      
    $dup = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM administrator WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($dup) >0){
            echo"<script language='JavaScript'> alert ('Username already use');</script>";
        echo '<script language="JavaScript"> window.location.href ="change_password.php" </script>';
        }
        } else {
    $query = mysql_query("update administrator set username='$username', password='$ecnrypt' where ID_Admin='$ID_Admin'") or die(mysql_error());


                            print '<script type="text/javascript">';
                            print 'alert("Profile has changed")';
                            print '</script>';

                            print '<script type="text/javascript">';
                            print "window.location.href='panelAdmin.php'";
                            print '</script>';}
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I think either the part of "if else" or "script alert" that make this file doesn't work.

Comment: 1. Stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated.. Use PDO or MYSQLI_* instead  2. SQL Injection alert!  3. Turn on error reporting?  4. Put some echo's to see how far your code gets executed?

Comment: blank pages means there is an syntax error. Can you output which error are you getting with it? You can see `php_error_log`.

Comment: @Naruto still using mysql for another file, and everything is okay, I think that's not the main problem :)

Comment: @bcesars I don't use localhost, I already hosting it.

Comment: @patrickstar19 I didn't say that was your main problem, I just pointed out it is A problem ;)

Comment: add  `error_reporting(E_ALL);  ini_set("display_errors", 1);`  at the beginning of your file, and see what error message are displayed.

Comment: @MarioA it says error in line 7, which line 7 is `$ID_Admin=$_POST['admin_id'];` you can check it, I already put the form for change password and username, thanks :)

Comment: have you checked Line 7 in `config.php` ?

Comment: @MarioA it says error Line 7 in change.php not in config.php, how?

Comment: Wha kind of error `$ID_Admin=$_POST['admin_id'];` outputs? Is there anything related to `undefined index`  ?

Comment: @bcesars it says `Notice: Undefined index: admin_id`, I just added the source code that used as a form to change username and password, kindly check my post above, I've edited it.

Comment: Got it. You didn't include an `input` tag inside your form that you can name it as "admin_id". your PHP code cannot find $_POST value since you try to passing it by POST. Adding `<input type="hidden" name="admin_id" value="$admin_id">` should work

Comment: @bcesars still blank :(

Comment: @patrickstar19 see my answer. It is enough and more complete since you need to input and variable inside the tag. If you see any other errors, please post it so we can help you.

Comment: @bcesars I already put it, but still blank, and displayed no error, but the file didn't redirecting to another page

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape your single quote so this:

```
 echo" <script language='JavaScript'> alert ('Password doesn't match');</script>";
```

should be this:

```
 echo" <script language='JavaScript'> alert ('Password doesn\'t match');</script>";
```

i'm guessing that is why its failing, also make sure your display_error() is enabled, to make sure you're not getting any PHP errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this where you have the redirects, just `window.location` will do the work for you:

```
echo '<script language="JavaScript">window.location = "change_password.php"; </script>';
```

Also, note the semicolon after .php"

Comment: Usually, when javascript doesn't redirect, you can check the source code to see if there's any script written.

Comment: I've been add my source code for file "change_password.php". That file is a form for Administrator change username and password.

Comment: Oh ok, so the password is not being updated, right? Try this: right before the `if ($confirm_pass != $password) {`, insert this line: `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no formelement in your form with the name `admin_id`. E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="admin_id" value=5" />
```

So the array $_POST has no index "admin_id", and thus the error message with the undefined index.

Answer (score 0):

Since your PHP code cannot find value passed via POST, you need to include an input named with `admin_id` inside your form.

Example:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="admin_id" value="<?php  echo $admin_id; ?>" />
```

That should fix your error about:

> Notice: Undefined index: admin_id

Comment: I already put it, but still blank, and displayed no error, but the file didn't redirecting to another page.

Comment: Which line you exactly include this `input` tag?

Comment: I include the input tag before `input` username, is it true?

Comment: Its true. But I think there is another error. Try to include `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`  inside your form page right exactly you did in `change.php` so we can see which errors output.

Comment: still, doesn't displayed any errors, so what should I do?

Comment: Man, you need to get access to this `php_error_log` in your host. It is important to check what kind of error you are facing it. I would ask you to edit your question including this `input` tag so I can analyze it. Also, if this is still the problem, try this: `<?php echo" <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"admin_id\" value=\"".$admin_id."\" />"; ?>`